# How to upload image from web service to tableview for Swift3?

Tags: ios, image, uitableview, swift3, uiimage

Rest web service is as follows. I would also like to use the Photo data in this tableviewCell.

```
{
        "moduleitems": [
            {
              "Module_id": 29,
              "Hotel_id": 1,
              "Module_Name": "Standart Oda",
              "Connected_Module": 24,
              "Photo": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAYAAAD0eNT6AAAABGdBTUEAALGOfPtRkwAAACBjSFJNAACHDwAAjA8AAP1SAACBQAAAfXkAAOmLAAA85QAAGcxzPIV3AAAKOWlDQ1BQaG90b3Nob3AgSUNDIHByb2ZpbGUAAEjHnZZ3VFTXFofPvXd6oc0wAlKG3rvAANJ7k15FYZgZYCgDDjM0sSGiAhFFRJoiSFDEgNFQJFZEsRAUVLAHJAgoMRhFVCxvRtaLrqy89/Ly++Osb+2z97n77L3PWhcAkqcvl5cGSwGQyhPwgzyc6RGRUXTsAIABHmCAKQBMVka6X7B7CBDJy82FniFyAl8EAfB6WLwCcNPQM4BOB/+fpFnpfIHomAARm7M5GSwRF4g4JUuQLrbPipgalyxmGCV="
        },,
        {
          "Module_id": 31,
          "Hotel_id": 1,
          "Module_Name": "Aile Odası",
          "Connected_Module": 24,
          "Photo": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAYAAAD0eNT6AAAABGdBTUEAALGOfPtRkwAAACBjSFJNAACHDwAAjA8AAP1SAACBQAAAfXkAAOmLAAA85QAAGcxzPIV3AAAKOWlDQ1BQaG90b3Nob3AgSUNDIHByb2ZpbGUAAEjHnZZ3VFTXFofPvXd6oc0wAlKG3rvAANJ7k15FYZgZYCgDDjM0sSGiAhFFRJoiSFDEgNFQJFZEsRAUVLAHJAgoMRhFVCxvRtaLrqy89/Ly++Osb+2z97n77L3PWhcAkqcvl5cGSwGQyhPwgzyc6RGRUXTsAIABHmCAKQBMVka6X7B7CBDJy82FniFyAl8EAfB6WLwCcNPQM4BOB/+fpFnpfIHomAARm7M5GSwRF4g4JUuQLrbPipgalyxmGCVm=
    }
```

Swift3  for TableView

```
 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Module?.list!.count ?? 0
    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.InfoLabel.text = Module?.list![indexPath.row].moduleName
        cell.InfoLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.InfoImage.image = UIImage(named: (Module?.list![indexPath.row].photo)!)
//            cell.InfoImage.image = Module?.list![indexPath.row].photo
        return cell
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How you're parsing this rest service response? have you created a model for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the answer to my question like this.**

```
if let imageDataString = (Module?.list?[indexPath.row].photo),
                let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: imageDataString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!,
                let img = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)
            {
                cell.InfoImage.image = img
            }else{
                cell.InfoImage.image = UIImage(named: "default_image")
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using `UIImage(named:)` instead of `UIImage(data: data)`. Do like this

```
if let imageDataString = (Module?.list?[indexPath.row].photo), let dataDecoded = Data(base64Encoded: imageDataString, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters), let img = UIImage(data: imageData){ 
   cell.InfoImage.image = img 
} else {
   cell.InfoImage.image = // set default/placeholder image
}
```

**PS:** I assume that you have parsed the JSON response and converted image data string into `Data`.

Comment: Error:  Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Data'

Comment: I mentioned that in PS. I updated my answer. Check now

Comment: do not add. The picture that I set as default is coming.

Comment: you should find whether you are getting proper imageData or not.

Comment: **It's true code line:** let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: imageDataString!, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!